# Excel - Rank top 3 students

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Screenshot of my issue]

This is the image regarding my issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1558452/edit) your post to include the details of what you've tried so far and what your desired outcome is. I know these are present in your image, but you will probably get a more positive response if you include them in the body of your post with a clearly marked question.

Comment: Hi @Vibhor Goel , which version of Excel you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel O365 with dynamic arrays and the `SORT` and `FILTER` functions, you could use:

*(Note that I converted the name/marks data into a **Table** and am using structured references. You can convert that to regular references if you prefer)*

```
F4: =ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA(G4#)))
G4: =INDEX(SORT(FILTER(tblStudRank,tblStudRank[Marks]>=LARGE(tblStudRank[Marks],3)),2,-1),0,1)
```

[image]

Brief algorithm:

- `SORT` the table by `Marks` and return all of the top three values
- Generate an array of `1..COUNT of values returned` for the Ranking

---

**EDIT:** The above returns a result like your #2.

To return a result like your #1, then use

```
F4: =IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((tblStudRank[Marks]> XLOOKUP(G4,tblStudRank[Student Name],tblStudRank[Marks]))/COUNTIF(tblStudRank[Marks],tblStudRank[Marks]))+1,"")
```

and fill down

```
G4: =INDEX(SORT(FILTER(tblStudRank,tblStudRank[Marks]>=LARGE(UNIQUE(tblStudRank[Marks]),3)),2,-1),0,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*This method has limitless scope since works with any version of Excel*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell `S148`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((R148<=$R$148:$R$157)/COUNTIF($R$148:$R$157,$R$148:$R$157))
  ```
- Formula in cell `T148`:

  `=IF(ROW(A1)<=4,SMALL(S$148:S$157,ROW(A1)),"")`
- Final array (CSE) formula in cell `U148`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Q:Q,SMALL(IF(S$148:S$157=T148,ROW(S$148:S$157)),COUNTIF(T$148:T148,T148))),"")}
  ```
- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.